# Why is length/2 getting me out of global stack?

Tags: exception, prolog, clpfd

when i commit the query:

```
?- X in 1..2, length(List,X).
```

the returning results are:

```
X = 1, List = [_1260];
X = 2, List = [_1260, _1266];
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term. Aborting.
% Execution Aborted
```

i thought this happened cause X isn't grounded, so i ran 3 more queries to see how length/2 bahaves with non-instantiated variables as length:

```
?- X in inf..sup, length(List,X).
?- length(List,_).
?- length(List,_X).
```

and all work properly. Thus, if X isn't grounded, after reaching domain's supremum, length/2 crashes. Why is this happening? Shouldn't it return **false** instead?

Comment: Prolog keeps on looking to generate a list with `length/2`, but each time the `X in 1..2` constraint fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening? Shouldn't it return `false` instead?

No, since `length/2` is not aware of these bounds, it simply suggests values, and the frozen constraint check each time rejects these values.

The [**`length/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) can be used in a "*constructive*" way. Indeed we can generate lists with their corresponding length like:

```
?- length(L, N).
L = [],
N = 0 ;
L = [_2316],
N = 1 ;
L = [_2316, _2322],
N = 2 ;
L = [_2316, _2322, _2328],
N = 3
...
```

Now you defined a constraint on `N`, which means that if you set `N` to a certain value, the Prolog interpreter will check if that value is in the `1..2` range. For each value with `N > 2`, that will thus fail. But `length/2` of course does *not* understand this range. It will keep suggesting lists and their corresponding lengths, and that will each time fail.

It is equivalent to:

```
?- length(L, N), member(N, [1, 2]).
L = [_2304],
N = 1 ;
L = [_2304, _2310],
N = 2 ;
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
ERROR: No room for exception term. Aborting.
```

Here it makes more sense to do this in reverse, like:

```
?- member(N, [1,2]), length(L, N).
N = 1,
L = [_3372] ;
N = 2,
L = [_3372, _3378].
```

Or in case that is not an option try to [**`freeze/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=freeze/2) the construction of the list until `N` is known.